# How to make in-memory data available to linux tools that accept path

Tags: python, linux

Assume I have `cat` and normally I pass there path to file that I want to read. And then I have another script in python that reads some data in memory. Is it possible somehow to pass that memory as file path in `cat` (or any other tool) without making it physical object on hard disk?

Comment: Did you try using system commands in python ?

Comment: @eiram_mahera I'm using subprocess.run, but what's the difference? I have to pass filepath anyway